# Having an SVR model with one dimensional input vector and 2 dimensional output vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I currently have two datasets. One gives me an output rational number corresponding to different input numbers. And the other gives me an output integer corresponding to the same input vector. The data looks pretty much like this -

```
X (input) = 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25
Y1 (output 1) = 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 1.1, 1.5, 1.9
Y2 (output 2) = 45, 47, 51, 60, 90, 100
```

While I have been successfully able to train two distinct SVR models using SVR from sklearn.svm as follows -

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
regressor.fit(X, Y1)
Y1_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(X, Y1).predict(X)
regressor.fit(X, Y2)
Y2_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(X, Y2).predict(X)
```

Is there a way for me to have multidimensional output using SVR? Like input vector as X and output vector as - [Y1, Y2]? No specific reason - I just want to reduce the amount of code and make everything concise.

P. S. I looked into this - https://github.com/nwtgck/multi-svr-python, this is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option would definitely be to use the [`sklearn.multioutput`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.multioutput) module and their offered regression and classification models.

They basically take a base estimator (`SVR` in your case) and use it to predict multiple labels. Depending on the actual model, this is achieved in different ways.The [`MultiOutputRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) for instance fits one regressor per target.

Its use would definitely make the code more concise:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR


X = np.asarray([0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.asarray([[0.2, 45], [0.4, 47], [0.7, 51], [1.1, 60], [1.5, 90], [1.9, 100]])

regressor = MultiOutputRegressor(SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1))

regressor.fit(X, y)
```